# Order elements by products price

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to order the different products from a website but can't do it correctly.

Basically I need to get the price of each one and order them from the most expensive one to the least one.

I tried the following code but it disappears everything and keeps not ordering them in the correct way:

```
var divList = $(".block-level.h2");
divList.sort(function(a, b){
    return $(a).data(".block-level.h2")-$(b).data(".block-level.h2")
});
$(".grid").html(divList);
```

I don't have access to modify the HTML so it has to be done with the code I have now, only can add things through jQuery.

Can someone give me a tip or help me out please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your request to sort the product grid items, here is the `jQuery` code that you can use.

```
var values = [];
$('.block-level.h2').each(function() {
    var temp = Array();
    temp['value'] = parseInt($(this).html().replace('$',''));
    temp['element'] = $(this).closest('.grid-item');
    values.push(temp);
});
values.sort(function(a,b) { return b.value - a.value; });
var sortedHtml = '';
$.each(values, function(index, obj) { 
    if((index+1)%3==1) {
        sortedHtml+=('<div class="grid product-cards__row"><div class="grid-item one-third palm-one-whole product-cards__item">'+$(obj.element).html()+'</div>');
    } else if((index+1)%3==0) {
        sortedHtml+=('<div class="grid-item one-third palm-one-whole product-cards__item">'+$(obj.element).html()+'</div></div>');
    } else {
        sortedHtml+=('<div class="grid-item one-third palm-one-whole product-cards__item">'+$(obj.element).html()+'</div>');
    }
});
$('.product-cards').html(sortedHtml);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow it works in a fantastic way, thank you so so much @Shekhar Chikara, I really appreciate your invaluable help!

Comment: @Cloud Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by the following code-

```
var values = Array();
$('.block-level.h2').each(function() {
    values.push(parseInt($(this).html().replace('$','')));
});
values.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
```

In your code above - the main problem is with `$(a).data(".block-level.h2")` since its trying to find an attribute with name `data-.block-level.h2` in element `a` which doesn't exist. That's why the empty result.

Comment: Thanks so much @Shekhar Chikara, the order is fine now! Can I bother you with one more question please? I'm trying to move the products so that the appear in order in the design, do you know how can I apply this?

Comment: Yeah, so if you want to keep the order that is there on the page, you can simply keep the `values` array before applying the `sort()` function. That will have the original sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again, sorry probably I didn't explain what I need in a correct way.

Once everything is order from maximum to minimum I need to remove the actual packages that they're seen in the website when you get inside and order show them again but with the new order. Right now with your code I'm  seeing them in order through the console but when I try to modify it to move the products in the design I'm not quite getting it.

Thank you again for everything!

Comment: So you want to change the listing to use the same order as your sorted values array?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I want to order them (as you showed me above) from maximum to minimum price and then apply that in the visual design, to move the products in that order so that users can see them that way inside the website.

Thank you again so much for all your invaluable help @Shekhar Chikara!